# Google Sheets - How can I move a row to another sheet based on multiple criteria?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to move a row from sheet "Loads" to sheet "Invoiced Loads" based on multiple criteria. The criteria is:

If the load has been *Delivered* and *Invoiced* (which is a number greater than 0) move the load/row to sheet "Delivered".

I have seen many people have asked this question and I found a code that works, but only with one criteria. I have tried to modify the code so it checks the two conditions but I can not make it work. I ran out of options. Please if someone can help me I will really appreciate it. I know the solution must be really simple but I am a beginner on this and I am not sure which path to take please!!. The code I got at the moment is the below:

```
function onEdit(event) {

// assumes source data in sheet named Loads
// target sheet of move to named Invoiced Loads
// test column with "Delivered" is, col 19 or S
// test column with invoice number is, col 27 or AA

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if((s.getName() == "Loads" && r.getColumn() == 19 && r.getValue() == "Delivered") && 
 (s.getName() == "Loads" && r.getColumn() == 27 && r.getValue() > 0)) {

var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoiced Loads");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The main issue with the if statement is that `r.getColumn()` can't be
  `19` and `27` at the same time but also `r.getValue()` can't be
  `"Delivered"` and `>0` at the same time. As a result, the if
  condition will always evaluate to **false**.
- Also you don't need to evaluate twice for the same condition. The if
  condition in your code evaluates twice the expression `s.getName() == "Loads"` which is unnecessary. One is enough.
- This is an `onEdit` function which means that every time you make a
  change, `event.range.getRow()` and `event.range.getColumn()` will
  give you the coordinates of the cell that was edited. There is no
  need of using `event.source.getActiveRange();`.

---

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const row = event.range.getRow();
  const col = event.range.getColumn();
  const as = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  const numColumns = as.getLastColumn();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoiced Loads");
  const target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

  if(as.getName() == "Loads" && as.getRange(row,19).getValue() == "Delivered" 
  && as.getRange(row,27).getValue() >0) {

   as.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
   as.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Comment: I know I must avoid this type of comment but I have to thank you for your help. Thanks :)